# Proving that $a+b+c $ is composite knowing it divides $abc$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Assume $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers such that $(a+b+c)$ divides $abc$.  Show that $a+b+c$ is composite

I have that so far,

If $a+b+c$ is prime, then letting $a = xd$, $b = yd$, and $c = zd$ we have that $d(x+y+z)$ is prime. This means that $d = 1$ and thus $a,b,c$ are relatively prime. Therefore, $\dfrac{xyz}{x+y+z}$ is supposed to be an integer. What next?

Comment: What have  you tried? Here's a hint: assume that $a + b + c$ is prime and try to find a contradiction.

Comment: If $a+b+c$ is prime, then letting $a = xd$, $b = yd$, and $c = zd$ we have that $d(x+y+z)$ is prime. This means that d = 1 and thus $a,b,c$ are relatively prime. Therefore, $\dfrac{xyz}{x+y+z}$ is supposed to be an integer. What next?

Comment: Use the fact that if $m,n$ are integers and $p$ divides $mn$, then $p$ must divide $m$ or $n$.

Comment: Therefore, I conclude that $x+y+z$ must share a common factor with at least one of $x, y,$ and $z$. Is this possible?

Comment: I meant go back to the start of the problem and observe that if $a + b + c$ is prime, since $a + b + c$ divides $abc$, we have that $a + b + c$ must divide at least one of $a,b,c$. What's the problem with that?

Comment: It can't since it is a prime greater than them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31979/discussion-between-user1196158-and-ethan-alwaise).