# Prove that if $a+b+c$ divides $abc$, then $a+b+c$ must be composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have seen another post for this same question but it never got an answer. Since I am fairly new, I can't comment on other's posts, therefore I am creating a new one. The question states: 
If a, b, and c are positive integers, prove that if $(a + b + c) | (a*b*c)$, then $a+b+c$ is composite.

I do not really know how to approach this.

The link to the post with the same question is:
[Proving that $a+b+c $ is composite knowing it divides $abc$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542094/proving-that-abc-is-composite-knowing-it-divides-abc)

Comment: You should at least provide a link to the question so we can find it.  Please click the edit button, then there will be a link icon you can click on.

Comment: @RossMillikan Done - thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $a+b+c=p$ is prime. (It is greater than $1$, so that's the only way it can fail to be composite.) Then we have $a<p$, $b<p$ and $c<p$, so $p$ doesn't divide any of the three. Therefore, it does not divide their product, either.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you! I was way over thinking it. Should I delete this post since you answered on the other one as well?

Comment: Since the other questioner may be long gone, I guess I'd prefer that you accept the answer on this one. I'm not sure if that's contrary to SE norms, though.

Comment: You should post your answer either here or the old question, not both places.

Comment: Should I delete the other answer, and instead link to this question in the comments?

Comment: I will close the old one as a dupe of this, so your answer gets better  exposure.

Comment: Actually the same answer is in the comments/chat on the old question.

Comment: Oh, is it? I should have read those more carefully. I'll delete my answer there.

Comment: Just one minor gripe: not all positive integers are either prime or composite (though sums of three positive integers are).

Comment: Good point, Marc. Edited accordingly. Thanks.